# Update CMake in Ubuntu Linux without affecting ROS2 installation

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I want to update my CMake version (from 3.16.3 to 3.27.7) in my Ubuntu Linux environment without affecting the current ROS2 galactic installation. I installed the latest CMake version from this link : https://cmake.org/download/ and I installed from latest release 3.27.7 and from Linux x86_64 the .sh version. But since ROS2 galactic has a pre-installed CMake distribution deleting version 3.16.3 means that the whole ROS2 distribution will  also be deleted. So I need a way to apply 3.27.7 version to my system without losing ROS2.

I did a little search on the web but did not find anything similar.

The only link I found was this one : https://answers.ros.org/question/293119/how-can-i-updateremove-cmake-without-partially-deleting-my-ros-distribution/ but it uses `./bootstrap` this command while this file does not exist in order to execute it. So this solution does not work.

I also asked ChatGPT the same question but the answer it gave me either did not manage to aplly the newest version or it applied an incomplete version of CMake without applying all it's features and when i did `cmake --version`  I got this error : `CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!! CMake has most likely not been installed correctly. Modules directory not found in`.

So my question is how can I do have the latest CMake version (3.27.7) without affecting my ROS2 galactic disribution.

Thanks!

Comment: nothing to stop you having both the system cmake packages and the latest cmake installed at the same time, they should be independent as long as they're installed in separate folders

Comment: They are installed in seperate folders but `cmake --version` outputs `3.16.3` and I need to set the newer one as the main version

Comment: then update your path so that the new version's folder is first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the PATH. Here is an example of how you can do this with bash:

```
PATH="~/Downloads/cmake/3.27.3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

The important thing is I am `pre-pending` to the `PATH` to ensure my version of CMake is found first.

If you need the change to persist add the above code to `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` or `.bash_profile` whichever you prefer.

Comment: I'd put it in `.bash_profile`

Comment: I added it in `.bashrc` but is there a difference between `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Basically typing `ls -a` command does not show a `.bash_profile`